# NetBeans RCP application classpath

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath, classloader, rcp

I am developing NetBeans RCP application. The application consists of several modules, all modules (and also the application project itself) are managed by maven. I need to add custom jar to the application classpath. Is there easy way to do it? Especialy, I need to add the classpaths of every module for the application to be able to load module dependencies as this:

ModuleXxx has dependency on LibXxx
ModuleYyy has dependency on ModuleXxx

I need to get LibXxx jar path, which should be in the module classpath.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is LibXxx.jar available from a Maven repository or as a Maven project? Or is it just a jar you have from somewhere?

Comment: LibXxx is available from Maven repository, localy copied in the .m2 repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have thought a simple Maven dependency from ModuleXxx to LibXxx should be enough. Did you try that? Any issues?

Comment: no, that is wrong, because then you have "jar" only for your module. You must not have one "jar" in modular system twice (except some exceptions).

Comment: @user1722245 This is an old answer and I haven't worked with NetBeans RCP, but generally if several Maven Modules have a dependency on jar X, you don't end up with several copies of X. You will have only copy in your application.

Comment: to @user1722245: sorry, but modular system like OSGi or NetBeans RCP work differently. Each bundle/module has SELF own classpath, which can be extended with dependency (based on MANIFEST extra instructions) to other bundle (better package) / module  (RCP).  So your comment is wrong. Your answer is for application with "ONE classpath" only.  You dont work with RCP, that true.

Comment: typo: "I haven't worked with NetBeans RCP" *for some time now*

Comment: @user1722245: You're mixing runtime classpaths with static build-time dependency trees. When you assembly an application you usually only provide one copy of each module jar. Every module has its own ClassLoader and a tree of dependent ClassLoaders. At least that's how I'm currently working with the OSGi-based Drombler FX applications and as far as I remember it was similar with NetBeans RCP.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add "jar" to classpath, because netbeansrcp is SET of modules, which has own independent classpath ;-) So, you should create new module, which has in dependency "jar" (by maven for example) and then in pom.xml. Then set in your dependent module dependency to new LibWrappedModule

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>nbm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2</version>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<configuration>
                <publicPackages>
                    <publicPackage>com.mycompany.textfilter</publicPackage>
                </publicPackages>

</configuration>
```

more information is there https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/70/nbm-maven-quickstart.html